# How does delete exactly work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

Please check the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/du8svaym/

```
var a = [2, 4, "bang", undefined, NaN, 5];

for (i in a)
alert(a[i]); //alerting a[3]=undefined

delete a[1];
for (i in a)
alert(a[i]); //Why not alerting a[1]= undefined?

alert(a[1]); //it is undefined! but not alerted, what is happening under the hood?
```

If you notice, the first loop alert alerts a value which is undefined. In the 2nd loop alert a[1] is undefined since we deleted it, but is not alerted. What is the difference between the two undefined, how exactly or differently is delete setting the undefined?

Comment: Because its deleting from array. And the loop you are using it will traverse array by *elements of array* and **not from 0 to 5**

Comment: So? that does not answer my question

Comment: Please go through this i think it will help you to understand the concept http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html

Comment: deleting does not change the array length. You can confirm. So it is not removing the element.

Comment: @NikhilPai delete does change the array length BUT it does not update the .length property. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements

Comment: Fine, it changes the array length, any way to get the updated length since the .length property is not updated?

Comment: @NikhilPai Yup, don't use delete, use Array#splice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Example:_Using_splice

Answer (score 2):

The `delete` operator removes a property from an object. Arrays are JavaScript objects like so:

```
var foo = {
  '0': 2,
  '1': 4,
  '2': "bang",
  '3': undefined, 
  '4': NaN,
  '5': 5
}
delete foo[1]; // completely removes the property '1' from foo.
console.log(foo);
// outputs:
{
  '0': 2,
  '2': "bang",
  '3': undefined, 
  '4': NaN,
  '5': 5
}
```

Comment: Sorry for delayed edit, got pulled away straight after I noticed crucial typo but before I could rectify it! :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first iteration, the array looks like this.

```
[0: 2, 1: 4, 2: "bang", 3: undefined, 4: NaN, 5: 5]
```

Now, after you delete a[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), it removes 4. So, now the array looks like

```
[0: 2, 2: "bang", 3: undefined, 4: NaN, 5: 5]
```

Now, as you can see a[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does not exist. So it gives undefined.

Deleting an element will not affect the array length, as it does not change the indexes. If you want the array index to be affected, use **[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)**.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Arrays are sparse, that means that they do not have to store a value at every position. Delete removes the value at the position, making it sparse.

Try this

```
a = []; // empty array
a[1000] = 'hello';
for (i in a) {
    console.log(i);
}
console.log(a.length)
```

You will see that it will only print 1000 in the loop whereas the length of the array is 1001

Comment: I know this. What is the difference between a[1] which becomes undefined after deleting and a[3] which is undefined

Comment: `a[3]` is defined to be `undefined`. `a[1]` *really is* undefined.

Comment: Right, so a[1] really is undefined. How is that set to undefined

Comment: As there is no value, for the index 1 in the array, it shows 'undefined'. Look at my answer.